# How to setState with the array that has push method?

Tags: reactjs

My main goal is to set a state with a array of objects, but I can't do it because this array is mutated with elements that are pushed to it. I understand the problem but I don't know how to solve it

so here is code and I would like to set state with the final actors array. Any ideas?

```
    const moviesToMap = this.state.movies;
    moviesToMap.map(movie => {
      return this.state.title === movie.title
        ? movie.characters.map(person => {
            const actorUrl = person;
            const actorId = parseInt(actorUrl.slice(31, -1));
            let peopleStateCopy = this.state.people;
            peopleStateCopy.map(persona => {
              const slugState = persona.url;
              const slugId = parseInt(slugState.slice(31, -1));
              if (slugId === actorId) {
                actors.push(persona);
                return persona.name;
              }
            });
          })
```

Answer (score 0):

You've got a lot going on here - perhaps you could refactor this?

Where is your actors array initialized?  Where is your setState call?

When dealing with arrays in state, you may want to create a copy of your arrays - perform the mutations on the copy - and then set the state to the new array when you are finished.

For instance:

```
const moviesCopy = [...this.state.movies];
this.setState({ movies: moviesCopy });
```

Hope this helps get you on the right track.